# server push for django on dotcloud

Tags: python, django, server-push, dotcloud

What are the current options for implementing server push with a dotcloud app hosted django app? (similar to socket.io on node, channel api with appengine or apache comet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options are pretty much the same on dotCloud and on other environments. I.e., if we check [Django / Comet (Push): Least of all evils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310706/django-comet-push-least-of-all-evils), we learn that websockets won't play very nice with Django, but that asynchronous WSGI should be possible with http://code.google.com/p/evserver/.

I would personally use evserver using a dotCloud custom service; it should be fairly simple to support, and will provide clean long polling.

You can also use websockets, if you're not scared by django-websockets (or find some other way to do it).